# Android Push notification using Drupal HTTP Post error "Access denied for user anonymous"

Tags: android, drupal, drupal-7, push-notification

When I'm trying to register user on host url generated by drupal module it throws an error:

> "Access denied for user anonymous"

I'm sending Parameters

1. token=Reg id generated from GCM Google
2. type=android

Please any one help me to solve this ...

Comment: What are your authorization settings? It seems you failed to allow anonymous access to the registration form.

Comment: I m developing android part.Is this error from web drupal modul?

Comment: I guess you cannot be anything else, but anonymous during registration, so I think yes, the problem is there.

Comment: What is the content_type for that post request

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Enable permissions for anonymous user in Drupal administration - People/Permissions/Push permissions. It helped me.

Comment: but now I face a another problem,that notification is sending from drupal but it is not received on my android phone .... what should I do?please help

Comment: You need to have a Google account, create a project related to your App, activate the GCM Service and create an API key to be used as the configiration of your Drupal's Push Notification module. Read here: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/715415/Sending-Push-Notifications-from-a-Drupal-site